# mysql alter column allow null takes forever

Tags: mysql

I have a large table with a column that has currently NOT NULL
I now tried to alter the table to allow nulls for this column. However, the query never finishes. Is this to be expected or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I depends on what "large" means exactly. If you have 20 GB worth of data, yes, it's normal that it takes a while.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it has some 80M rows and >10GB

Answer (score 0):

That happens and I think the best approach is to create a new table schema and load the old table into that new table.